# Laravel 5: cannot pass data from Middleware to Controller

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am sending an ajax request with GET method to a controller

```
Route::get('test', ['Middleware' => 'TestFilter', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
```

The Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request); //This does not seem to pass $request to HomeController
}
```

In the index() method of HomeController I am trying to return $request but the page throws error

```
'Undefined variable: request' in D:\Apps\apilab\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php
```

I am simply returning `$request` in HomeController

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
  public function index() {
    return $request;
  }
}
```

How do I pass the request variable to HomeController@index so that I can continue processing?? I am exhausted of trying various methods...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. You are `return`ing twice - but only the first `return` will ever be processed.

Once your middleware is finished - just pass the $next($request) along - so it can be handled by the remainder of the framework

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request);
}
```

Then in your controller

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
  public function index(Request $request) {
    return $request;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, I have now edited the post. Still same error!

Comment: I've updated my answer - you need to inject the request into the controller